# My windows installation is not identified in bootrec /fixboot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bcd, bootmgr, bcdboot

I need to explain what exactly happened and what solutions I've tried

First of all my windows 10 build 1909 was working just fine and was fully updated. But windows update just constantly reminded me to update to 20H2 as support for my version soon will be ended (I happened to understand that it gets support until 2022 or something). I just decided to do so. so I download update assistant for 20H2 and let it download the update.

after it finished downloading (as it said so). it restart to do the update. but it stucked at 0% for near an hour. I just reset the PC and let it go back to previous windows so I do the update later.

in the startup it goes undoing changes made to the computer. after a 5-6 minutes it restarted and the same process happened. this went on for like 6-7 times and it looked like a looped pointless chains of restarts.

I decided to repair the windows to get back to my old version

so I downloaded 20h2 iso image and made a bootable stick.

I booted from this stick and went on to repair section.

Running on legacy BIOS. No EUFI and efi. simple mbr.
8 GB ram windows partition 78 gb on a 500GB HDD.

MB P7P55.

Now things that I observed:(I have 3 separate HDD)

1. C: was a 100 MB partition labeled "system reserved" on disk 0 with some files on it.  It is marked as active as detail in diskpart says.
2. there is another 100 MB partition like the above but on the disk 1  it is marked active too but has letter D assigned

3.My original windows installed partition letter changed to L and also is on disk 0 but is not active.

4. In the RE and on choose another operating system I have 2 options : 1 windows rollback or something like this. and one Windows 10 Option. First Opt leads to the looped startups. The other just do some diagnosing system and goes on to RE and says couldn't resolve problem and provide similar RE options as stick boot.

Things I've tried and failed.

first of all I did chkdsk with repair option

I marked the windows installed partition as active. but Nothing.

I found out after marking it active and restart this partition has letter C now but can't boot.

I fixed mbr with a 3rd party bootable app ( I used bootrec /fixmbr but no luck) after POST with original partition active I received 0xc000034  error saying something is missing boot\bcd.

Again in re I used bootrec /fixmbr successfully

used bootrec/fixboot and received "Access is denied"

bootrec /scanos returns: 0 identified installed windows.

bootrec /rebuildbcd also returns just like scan os and exits.

Used bootsect to update the bootsector(I geuess) like bootsect/nt60 c: /force (as with no force option it says access denied)

I even use ALL option to update all bootsect on all drives.

Even try to write a new.

Used bcdedit to backup and rename the bcd. no luck either.

bcdboot with any option returned "Failure when attempting to copy boot files".

I tried bootsect /nt60 sys /force and it successfully completed.

then the bootrec /fixboot does work once but bootrec /rebuildbcd didn't identify any windows installed.

i tried bootsect and then bcdboot but failure happened again.

tried bcdboot /bcdclean returns something like unable to clean store.

I think there is a problem with the partition configuration and it is somehow LOCKED or something because any attempt to manipulate the boot sector or boot record fails .Or even some missing files on C: that will show that here is an installed windows!.

Now Don't Tell me go for a clean install.

no bad HDD no new hardware no nothing. JUST fooled by update assistant.

Thank you guys

Comment: Try it again using build 1909. You may download the ISO from [link1](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-1909/) or [link2](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php). If Startup Repair doesn't work, try a Repair install.

Comment: Windows 10 version 1909 support will end 18 months from when it was released.  It was released on 11/12/2019 so support ends on 05/11/2021.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) question has numerous sources for Windows 10 version 1909 ISOs directly from Microsoft.  "windows rollback or something like this" - This description isn't helpful.  *We need to know exactly what was displayed.*

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for response. Does it matter which build I was using? I mean do I have to download exact version and build or just the version must be the same?

Comment: Roughly the same version should be enough. You might have difficulties finding the exact same version.

Comment: @harrymc I'll give it a try then.

Comment: @Ramhound The description is very helpful if you know the answer!  so you know the solution or you just don't. BTW that option now is off due my hard struggling with BCD and Boot.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  This vote is specifically with regards to the description "windows rollback or something like this", we need to know exactly what the option was, this will help better diagnose your issue.  **This is an personal commentary that copied the close vote rational.**