# How to download a Windows ISO from Microsoft using command-line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, iso-image

How can I download a Windows 10 ISO via command-line? If I use `curl` or `wget`, the ISO link from Microsoft is valid for only 24 hours.

Comment: The sad truth is that Microsoft does not want us to be able to access Windows ISOs via a permanent link. As far as I know there are only two options to get a valid ISO directly from Microsoft: using the windows media creation tool, or making the webpage believe that you access it from an apple device. As you cannot use the media creation tool on a Mac or an iPad, it gives you a temporary link to download an ISO file for the specific configuration you select on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer from github " https://github.com/pbatard/Fido "
Fido is a PowerShell script that is primarily designed to be used in Rufus, but that can also be used in standalone fashion, and whose purpose is to automate access to the official Microsoft Windows retail ISO download links.
GNU General Public License version 3.0 or later.
PowerShell 3.0 or later is required. However the script should detect if you are using an older version.
Because of its intended usage with Rufus, this script is not designed to cover every possible retail ISO downloads.

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell 5 or higher is installed, this will download the 64-bit version of Windows 10 version 21H1:

```powershell
# Source file location
$source = 'https://www.itechtics.com/?dl_id=140'

# Destination to save the file
$destination = 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\win10.iso'

# Download the source file and save it to destination
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination
```

- Change the destination path to a folder where you can save the file.
- Use [Download Windows 10 ISO Files (Direct Download Links)](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-download-iso/) to get links for other versions, then change the URL on the above commands.

Comment: Is this method valid only 24 hours?

Comment: @ChaniruRajapakse - Microsoft doesn’t offer permanent links to their ISOs for nearly any of their products. What you want is simply unrealistic. However, others have made a [PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) script that works, you might look into how that script works.

Comment: Please do not ask “how” to do this, I won’t answer, I will just flag the comment. The necessary script would have to be written by you to use bash (in my opinion that will be impossible)

Comment: Sorry @Reddy but who knows who itechtics.com is?! This is not an official Windows link. Who can tell what there is in that version? 
So why not downloading from a torrent?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Then the OP must find a direct link from Microsoft with no expiry date/time. He/She won't get it because the link from Microsoft comes with an expiry date and time. One of the solution left for the OP is to find a website where the file was uploaded and set for anyone to download. You do well to not trust any site. But the file is there to be downloaded and the Powershell commands from this answer allows to do exactly what the OP requested. By the way, I am not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Thank you @ReddyLutonadio

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to do that but not easily.

The only ISO you can download is the [Windows 10 Insider preview version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso) but you need to create a bot that click on that button and catch the link.

From there you can then use `curl` or `wget`.