# Where do I download windows to reinstall a ROG Zephyrus GA 15?

Tags: asus-laptop, asus-rog-zephyrus

I have a brand new ROG Zephyrus GA 15 that I'm replacing the SSD for a bigger one, so I have a completely blank SSD. Where can I download the correct version of Windows 10, with all Asus customizations, for this machine?

Comment: If you don't have problems with the current Windows 10 installation and you want to keep the Asus customizations you can simply clone the old SSD to the new SSD. But if you really want to re-install Windows 10 even the Asus FAQ just points to the Windows 10 images provided by Microsoft: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1039507/

Comment: @Robert I tried doing that, but it copies a layout of partitions that has some rescue stuff after C: (which appeared after D:), and prevents C: from being extended to the full size of the HD.

Comment: I would do the following: 1. Use an image backup tool like Macrium Free to create an backup of your main (the largest one) Windows partition to an external drive (not the full drive). 2. Then make a full fresh Windows 10 installation onto the new SSD, it will only create the necessary partitions. 3. Restore the backup image, overwriting the newly installed Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) question.  The RoG customizations can be downloaded from the specifications page for the device.  If you don’t feel you will get everything they sell external enclosures that will allow you to image your current SSD and restore it to the new SSD (which I assume is a M.2 NVMe drive).

Comment: Closing this question as duplicate of how to get a non Asus Windows 10 is just wrong. I know how to find a copy of Windows from Microsoft. I'm asking how to find a copy of Windows from Asus, for this laptop, with all the extra drivers and programs Asus adds, so that after installing it, it's the same as when it comes from the box. I'm voting to re-open, I don't need this anymore, but for the person that comes from Google, this is a slap on the face.