# windows 10 install, which device drivers is it looking for?

Tags: windows-10, installation, operating-systems

Booted the windows 10 installation media from USB on a new computer (which ask me to press any key to boot from cd or dvd :)

It complains about "No device drivers were found". **But doesn't say which one it's looking for.**

Everything seems to be detected if I use the Repair Command Prompt. Disks as are all seen (both HDD and nvme) network, video. I'm not missing anything. Yet I can't get past that driver selection screen. Already tried `diskpart` and created a new clean ntfs partition on the only HDD and set it as active.

Tried to download the drivers from the motherboard manufacturer. None of the uncompressed folders i point to find anything. Only the Sata Floppy driver finds a item and successfully loads it, but as expected, is utterly pointless.

Comment: It isn't clear where the problem is. Can you boot the installation media and later it complains there's no drives to install Windows on -or- it doesn't boot the installer?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a photo of the message? Screenshots are probably not an option.

Comment: Typically when the installation environment is looking for drivers it’s either because the disk is using MBR while the installation environment was booted in UUEFI mode or because the installation environment needs a driver (like a raid driver for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Still have no clue what driver it was looking for, but the solution is that sending the binary ISO image via `dd` to a USB drive does not work and you get the wrong installation program. The binary image works fine to install in a VM. so I installed there and then used the usb creation tool program (which microsoft annoyingly redirect you away, unless you send a fake user agent saying you are using windows already... and which also won't use the locally available ISO but instead download it again at 1mbps)

Here's how to know where you are:

if you see "press any key to boot from cd or dvd" you are on the wrong place.

if you see a very nice large 4k screen with crispy text you are on the wrong place.

If you see the windows 10 logo booting straight to the installer, you are good.

If you see a 800x640 screen with jagged text, you are good.

Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like an MBR vs GPT issue caused by the ISO you were using not supporting UEFI and/or having compatibility mode enabled. Outside of using the Media Creation Tool, Rufus makes the task of creating a working installation media disk, extremely easy.  Rufus even allows you to download the ISO[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).  The reason the dd created disk worked within a VM is likely due to the fact it was configured to use BIOS instead of UEFI otherwise you would have had a similar problem.  **BIOS implies MBR.**