# Feature Update is not suggested via "Windows settings" (update to 21H1)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm running a Windows 10 Pro 20H2. When I "check for Updates" through the Windows settings I should get offered <s>the 21H1</s> a feature update but it is not being displayed.

Is there a way to fix this?

Note: My approach was wrong, the 21H1 update is not offered anymore through "Windows Settings" -> "check for Updates".

Note: I know that I can update to 21H2 via `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10`, that is not what I want to do, I want to upgrade to 21H1.

Note: Since I started I found a way to download the update through the [msu file](http://b1.download.windowsupdate.com/d/upgr/2021/03/windows10.0-kb5000736-x64_880844224a175033802b3d7a1f40ec304c0548dd.msu) or the [cap file](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2021/05/windows10.0-kb5003173-x64_375062f9d88a5d9d11c5b99673792fdce8079e09.cab)) and to do the update manually (cap can be found via those sources: [source1](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/11-mai-2021-kb5003173-betriebssystembuilds-19041-985-19042-985-und-19043-985-2824ace2-eabe-4c3c-8a49-06e249f52527) [source2](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5003173), for the msu file I didn't find any "official" documentation, but quite a few tech sites do post the link). I tried the msu file, it's only 200kb, executing it triggers a restart after which it shows me that the current Win version is 21H1, however, 200kb seems a little small (and I didn't notice any significant additional download). Seems odd but I haven't researched this any further yet.

Comment: "My computer displays that what I wanted to do manually thru an unsupported way was successful, but I don't trust that this machine says the update was successful because it seemed to easy. How can I fix this?" Have I got this right?

Comment: *Enjoy WPA3 H2E standards support for enhanced Wi-Fi security

Get GPU compute support in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Azure IoT Edge for Linux on Windows (EFLOW) deployments for machine learning and other compute intensive workflows* is what it does.  Click *See What's In This Update* then select on the web page the feature update you interested in (it defaults to Win 11).

Comment: @user1644677 hows is your comment suppose to help to answer the question?

Comment: @mashuptwice No, I want to know how I can fix the problem that the feature update  doesn't show up through the Windows settings (when you choose "check for updates"). The alternative way (using the msu file to do the update) is just a side note.

Comment: @Albin - Did you set the group policy that forces you to stay on a specific feature release by chance?  I seem to recall submitting an answer, about that policy, to one of your questions in the past.  The policy is `Select the target Feature Update version` if you are wondering.  Provide the settings for [these](https://media.askvg.com/articles/images7/Set_Target_Feature_Update_Version_Windows_10_Group_Policy_Editor.png) group policies and I will update my answer.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, I just checked, but it's not set.

Comment: @Albin - Post a screenshot of your Update History.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running a Windows 10 Pro 20H2. When I "check for Updates" through the Windows settings I should get offered the 21H1 a feature update but it is not being displayed.

There are several reasons 21H1 is not being offered, the most relevant reason is that 21H2 is the current Windows 10 version.  **There is also a chance the entitlement package is already installed.**

> I know that I can update to 21H2 via https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10, that is not what I want to do, I want to
> upgrade to 21H1

There are other ways to get the Windows 10 21H1 ISO.  [This](https://uupdump.net/known.php?q=19043) is the simplest method.  [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10/1108086#1108086) is another method.

> since I started I found a way to download the update through the msu files or the cap file) and to do the update manually (via those sources: source1 source2). I tried the msu file, it's only 200kb, executing it triggers a restart after which it shows me that the current Win version is 21H1, however, 200kb seems a little small (and I didn't notice any significant additional download). Seems odd but I haven't researched this any further yet.

Based on the description, [KB5000736](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5000736-featured-update-to-windows-10-version-21h1-by-using-an-enablement-package-75a01e67-3b5f-4677-8efe-42852e41c7cf) is the enablement package for Windows 10 21H1.  I am not entirely sure, where you located the file, but it wasn't the Windows Update Catalog. I suspect you simply downloaded the right update from the Windows Update Catalog and it was automatically installed for you.

Comment: Based on the description of kb5000736 it appears to be the 21H1 enablement package.  By the way, if my answer did not actually answer your question, you shouldn't accept it.  It shouldn't have been possible to find that file, Microsoft indicates, it's NOT in the Microsoft Update Catalog.

Comment: No, you actually answered my question, the point was to get a 21H1 Version of Windows, to just download a 21H1 image and reinstalling works fine, I don't necessary need to get there through an update.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not a computer tech or anything but have sure learned a lot going thru every single thing ppl recommend to fix the failed update to 20H2.

After many hours and knowing I had disabled Malewarebytes with no success, I completely UNINSTALLED Malewarebytes.

And now 20H2 update has downloaded and is installing, albeit quite slowly. Up to 12% right now and crossing my fingers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).