# You can't keep your files, apps, and settings because the version of Windows you're installing is different from the one you're currently using

Tags: windows-10, reinstall

To fix a network issue on my computer, I installed the `MediaCreationTool21H2.exe` and generated a Windows 10 ISO (windows10.iso).  However, after running Setup.exe, I can only choose options that would result in a clean installation of Windows.

I also receive the following error:

`You can't keep your files, apps, and settings because the version of Windows you're installing is different from the one you're currently using`

I have attempted to locate a solution to this problem.  However, I could only find answers to the issues different from my situation.  I am trying to find a solution, but I can still choose to keep my files.

In detail, there are three choices to reinstall my system

- keep my files and apps
- only keep my files
- delete all data

However, I can only select the second and the third option.

My windows version is `Windows 21H2` Professional version.
What can I do to reinstall the system with keeping my files and apps?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeS3K.jpg]

**Translation**:

> version: Windows 10 Pro
> version number: 21H2
> The date of installation: 2022/4/28
> Operating system version: 19044.1706
> Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

I mounted the iso file and ran the setup.exe

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of `System -> About` by submitting a [edit] to your question?  If you are getting the message you received, then you are attempting to wrong edition of Windows, which means you might not actually have the edition you think you have installed.  Are you mounting the ISO that is created within Windows and then running the Setup.exe and the mounted virtual drive?  Do not reply to this comment with another comment you should only [edit] your question.

Comment: You didn't provide the information I need to answer your question.  It's also not in English, you can provide a translation for us, but I know no other language except English.  It's worth pointing out that the Media Creation Tool, is context-aware of the system that is downloading the ISO, so if you downloaded it on a Windows 10 Home system then that's what it created. My suggestion is either download the [ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/) using a different method or download it through [this](https://uupdump.net/) website in order to generate the exact ISO you want.

Comment: There is only one reason you would receive the error you received, that's if you were attempting to install the wrong edition of Windows 10, while within a different Windows 10 installation.  If you provide the screenshot I need to answer your question I will submit an answer.

Comment: Can you provide specifics of the machine that ran the Media Creation Tool?  Provide this information as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to reinstall the system with keeping my files and apps?

The only reason you would receive the error "You can't keep your files, apps, and settings because the version of Windows you're installing is different from the one you're currently using" is because the ISO that you are attempting to use was for a different edition of Windows 10.

It's remotely possible if the machine that downloaded the ISO you created, was in a different language, that also could generated the message you recieved.

The simplest solution to your problem is instead of using the Media Creation Tool, which is context-aware of the edition of the system it's run on, is to use a different method to download the current Windows 10 21H2 ISO.

There are three methods I would recommend to download the correct Windows 10 ISO.

- You can either download the current Windows 10 ISO directly from Microsoft, by changing your browser's user agent, to something other than Windows.
- You can use one of many websites, that present the ISO directly from ISO, but are simply a link on their website.  You can find those websites, in the existing question, [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)
- You can use a website like [UUP dump](https://uupdump.net/), which will give specific parameters, and create the correct ISO you need.

Answer (score 0):

even this issue seems to be 2 years old, following post from my digital life helped me:

https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/discussion-windows-10-final-build-19041-19045-pc-20h1-22h2-vb_release.80763/page-262#post-1625428

```
https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/discussion-windows-10-final-build-19041-19045-pc-20h1-22h2-vb_release.80763/page-267#post-1626621

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EditionVersion] <---Take ownership of this key

"EditionBuildBranch"="vb_release"

"EditionBuildLab"="19041.vb_release.191206-1406"

"EditionBuildLabEx"="19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406"

"EditionBuildNumber"=dword:00004a62 <---Modify this key to the 4a61 value.

"EditionBuildQfe"=dword:0000023c <---Modify this key to the 1fc value.
```

After changing, a reboot, and it worked