# Windows Update causing Kernel Security Check Failure

Tags: windows-10

I recently upgraded my Alienware Aurora R7 desktop from a 1TB SSD to a 4TB SSD and had to set up a new Windows install.  I followed the directions from Dell using their system recovery tool to create a USB book drive and it sets me up with Windows 10 Build 19041.264, which is obviously pretty old. Now the problem: When I use Windows Update, I go to reboot, and suddenly I get Kernel Security Check Failures. All the solutions I can find involve getting into the computer somehow but these show up extremely early, I can't even F12 on this boot cycle successfully. It fails with BSOD, reboots, fails immediately, reboots, and sends me to recovery. I try to load Safe Mode in various ways, same issue arises.

Is there a better way I can do this? Some useful way to clone my install? My old SDD is in an enclosure and I *can* boot from it by USB, which may give me options (can you move a system restore point, perhaps?).

In any case, I want the security updates and I have software that won't run on the old version of Windows, so how can I resolve this? How can I even investigate this?

Comment: “Is there a better way I can do this?” - Download the 0[Windows Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) directly from Microsoft and install Windows 10 22H2[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)

Comment: Regardless of what solution you ultimately use, your current (new) installation of Windows cannon be used, and will require you to reinstall Windows 10. This will at a minimum require you to change the boot order of your machine.

Comment: After installing Windows 10 22H2, check your hardware. In case of a problem, you might need to download a driver from Dell. Don't install Dell drivers for devices that work perfectly well.